# Pagination for complex postgres queries

Tags: postgresql, performance, pagination

I am working on a complex normalized database, and generating a dynamic Product offering.

The Current query runs relatively fast, but generates 1K+ rows, and I need to implement a pagination solution.

In query is relatively complex to get all the information needed to build the dynamic data

```
FROM pulse_templates pt
INNER JOIN taggings ptags on ptags.taggable_type = 'PulseTemplate' AND ptags.taggable_id = 
pt.id AND ptags.context = 'available_for'
INNER JOIN schools s on s.id = 1
LEFT JOIN mascots m on m.id = s.mascot_id
LEFT JOIN pulse_designs pd on pd.id = m.silhouette_id
INNER JOIN colors_pulse_templates cpt ON cpt."pulse_template_id" = pt."id"
INNER JOIN items i on (pt.template_type = 'static' AND cpt."color_id" = i."primary_color_id") OR (pt.template_type = 'primary' AND s.primary_color_id = i.primary_color_id AND i.primary_color_id = cpt.color_id) or (pt.template_type = 'standard' AND i.primary_color_id = cpt.color_id AND (i.primary_color_id = s.primary_color_id OR i.primary_color_id = s.secondary_color_id OR i.primary_color_id = s.tertiary_color_id))
INNER JOIN taggings itags on itags.taggable_type = 'Item' AND itags.taggable_id = i.id AND itags.tag_id = ptags.tag_id AND ptags.context = 'available_for'
INNER JOIN tags tag on tag.id = itags.tag_id
INNER JOIN categories c on (c.id = i.category_id)
INNER JOIN pulse_products pp on pp.id = i.pulse_product_id
INNER JOIN product_lines pl on pl.id = i.product_line_id
WHERE
        s.id = 1 AND ((pt.all_identifiers LIKE '%mascot_name%' AND pd.id IS NOT NULL) OR pt.all_identifiers NOT LIKE '%mascot_name%')
GROUP BY s.id,pp.id,i.id,pt.id,pl.price
```

and the Performance is tolerable

```
Total query runtime: 1 secs 810 msec.
1365 rows affected.
```

But when I try to implement pagination using LIMIT/OFFSET, it goes out the window.

```
Total query runtime: 10 secs 737 msec.
25 rows affected.
```

With that kind of performance hit, I am almost better to move the pagination out of the database, and into the Server code.

Is there a good way of implementing Pagination for a public website that doesn't come with this much additional processing time?

Comment: "I am almost better to move the pagination out of the database, and into the Server code."  Yes, indeed.  That is a good spot for it.

Comment: If you want help to make it faster in the database, please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for both the fast and slow versions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `WITH HOLD` cursors:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT ...;
```

Then you can fetch pages with

```
FETCH 25 FROM c;
```

Such cursors are materialized on the server, so you must make sure to close the cursor when you are done to free the resources:

```
CLOSE c;
```

Note that such cursors are closed automatically when the database session ends.

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion, and please forgive my ignorance here.  You mention that we need to close the cursor when we are done.  With this being public facing, we won't know when the User is done browsing, so wouldn't we need to rebuilding the cursor for every request?

Comment: @tezyn, Do you know when the user has logged out, either explicitly or by session expiration?

Comment: Laurenz Albe and jjanes Thanks both for your input.  I am going to need to so some more reading on Cursor handling before I can see if this will work for us.  but I appreciate you taking the time to give me ideas.